# Error during template rendering | Could not parse the remainder: '(pandas.NaT)' from 'pandas.isnull(pandas.NaT)'

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to display a dictionary via html in django app and that each value of dictionary is a dataframe.

I'm able to print key but not dataframe for which I've tried many different approaches.

Either I get key value pair printed which is not very human readable or I get `Could not parse the remainder` error

Here's snippet of views.py

```
            context = {'rail': rail}

            return render(request, 'sample_output.html', context)
```

where rail is my dictionary

Here's snippet of html

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for key in rail.keys %}
                <th>{{ key }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;">
            {% for key, value in rail.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        {% for index, row in value.iterrows %}
                        <tr>
                            {% for cell in row %}
                              <td>
                                {% if cell is not pandas.isnull(pandas.NaT) %}
                                    {{ cell }}
                                {% else %}
                                    NaT
                                {% endif %}
                              </td>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </tr>
                          {% endfor %}

                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
   
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) with [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter:

```
context = {'rail': {k: v.to_html() for k, v in rail.items()}}
```

For each dataframe, in your template use `<td>{{ value|safe }}</td>`

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
print(df.to_html())

# Output
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry sir but could you please let me know where in template I insert this statement and .to_html() is for dataframes right whereas rail is a dictionary whose each value is individual dataframe

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. Convert each dataframe of your dictionary as an html table.

Comment: Yes sir that's what I'm failing to do as few values of those dataframes are NaT

Comment: What is the problem with NaT? If you use `to_html()`, I think you won't have any problem.

Comment: I updated my code, can you check it please?

Comment: Thanks sir, html was missing how to code using | safe but I've used your guidance to improve the overall result.

Comment: I would request if possible to include <td>{{ value|safe }}</td> so that other's may benefit from it too